# Back-propagation and forward-propagation for 2 hidden layers in neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning

My question is about forward and backward propagation for deep neural networks when the number of hidden units is greater than 1.

I know what I have to do if I have a single hidden layer. In case of a single hidden layer, if my input data `X_train` has `n` samples, with `d` number of features (i.e. `X_train` is a `(n, d)` dimensional matrix, `y_train` is a `(n,1)`  dimensional vector) and if I have `h1` number of hidden units in my first hidden layer, then I use `Z_h1 = (X_train * w_h1) + b_h1` (where `w_h1` is a weight matrix with random number entries which has the shape `(d, h1)` and `b_h1` is a bias unit with shape `(h1,1)`. I use sigmoid activation `A_h1 = sigmoid(Z_h1)` and find that both `A_h1` and `Z_h1` have shapes `(n, h1)`. If I have `t` number of output units, then I use a weight matrix `w_out` with dimensions `(h1, t)` and `b_out` with shape `(t,1)` to get the output `Z_out = (A_h1 * w_h1) + b_h1`. From here I can get `A_out = sigmoid(Z_out)` 
 which has shape `(n, t)`. **If I have a 2nd hidden layer (with h2 number of units) after the 1st hidden layer and before the output layer, then what steps must I add to the forward propagation and which steps should I modify?**

I also have idea about how to tackle backpropagation in case of single hidden layer neural networks. For the single hidden layer example in the previous paragraph, I know that in the first backpropagation step `(output layer -> hidden layer1)`, I should do `Step1_BP1: Err_out = A_out - y_train_onehot` (here `y_train_onehot` is the onehot representation of `y_train`. `Err_out` has shape `(n,t)`. This is followed by `Step2_BP1: delta_w_out = (A_h1)^T * Err_out` and `delta_b_out = sum(Err_out)`. The symbol `(.)^T` denotes the transpose of matrix. For the second backpropagation step `(hidden layer1 -> input layer)`, we do the following `Step1_BP2: sig_deriv_h1 = (A_h1) * (1-A_h1)`. Here `sig_deriv_h1` has shape `(n,h1)`. In the next step, I do `Step2_BP2: Err_h1 = \Sum_i \Sum_j [ ( Err_out * w_out.T)_{i,j} * sig_deriv_h1__{i,j} )`]. Here, `Err_h1` has shape `(n,h1)`. In the final step, I do `Step3_BP2: delta_w_h1 = (X_train)^T  * Err_h1` and `delta_b_h1 = sum(Err_h1)`. **What backpropagation steps should I add if I have a 2nd hidden layer (h2 number of units) after the 1st hidden layer and before the output layer? Should I modify the backpropagation steps for the one hidden layer case that I have described here?**

Comment: What are you working with? Tensorflow/numpy or something else?

Comment: I am trying to code up the forward and backward propagation steps in an ab initio manner (i.e. not using tensorflow or any package.)

Comment: This is covered in the coursera's deep learning module, as per the Code of Conduct in Coursera's agreement, I am not allowed to upload parts of code from that, but many have uploaded there's to GitHub, here is the link for one on the same https://github.com/enggen/Deep-Learning-Coursera/blob/master/Neural%20Networks%20and%20Deep%20Learning/Building%20your%20Deep%20Neural%20Network%20-%20Step%20by%20Step.ipynb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

● Let **X** be a matrix of samples with shape `(n, d)`, where `n` denotes number of samples, and `d` denotes number of features.

● Let **w<sub>h1</sub>** be the matrix of weights - of shape `(d, h1)` , and

● Let **b<sub>h1</sub>** be the bias vector of shape `(1, h1)`.

You need the following steps for **forward** and **backward** propagations:

► **FORWARD PROPAGATION:**

⛶ ***Step 1:***

**Z<sub>h1</sub>        =         [ X    •     w<sub>h1</sub> ]      +      b<sub>h1</sub>**

↓                        ↓           ↓                   ↓

`(n,h1)`     `(n,d)`   `(d,h1)`     `(1,h1)`

Here, the symbol • represents matrix multiplication, and the `h1` denotes the number of hidden units in the first hidden layer.

⛶ ***Step 2:***

Let **Φ()** be the activation function. We get.

**a<sub>h1</sub>     =      Φ (Z<sub>h1</sub>)**

↓                   ↓

`(n,h1)`       `(n,h1)`

⛶ ***Step 3:***

Obtain new weights and biases:

● **w<sub>h2</sub>** of shape `(h1, h2)`, and

● **b<sub>h2</sub>** of shape `(1, h2)`.

⛶ ***Step 4:***

**Z<sub>h2</sub>        =         [ a<sub>h1</sub>    •     w<sub>h2</sub> ]      +      b<sub>h2</sub>**

↓                        ↓             ↓                   ↓

`(n,h2)`     `(n,h1)`   `(h1,h2)`     `(1,h2)`

Here, `h2` is the number of hidden units in the second hidden layer.

⛶ ***Step 5:***

**a<sub>h2</sub>     =      Φ (Z<sub>h2</sub>)**

↓                   ↓

`(n,h2)`       `(n,h2)`

⛶ ***Step 6:***

Obtain new weights and biases:

● **w<sub>out</sub>** of shape `(h2, t)`, and

● **b<sub>out</sub>** of shape `(1, t)`.

Here, `t` is the number of classes.

⛶ ***Step 7:***

**Z<sub>out</sub>        =         [ a<sub>h2</sub>    •     w<sub>out</sub> ]      +      b<sub>out</sub>**

↓                          ↓            ↓                   ↓

`(n,t)`       `(n,h2)`   `(h2,t)`     `(1,t)`

⛶ ***Step 8:***

**a<sub>out</sub>     =      Φ (Z<sub>out</sub>)**

↓                   ↓

`(n,t)`       `(n,t)`

► **BACKWARD PROPAGATION:**

⛶ ***Step 1:***

Construct the one-hot encoded matrix of the unique output classes ( **y<sub>one-hot</sub>** ).

**Error<sub>out</sub>     =     a<sub>out</sub>   -   y<sub>one-hot</sub>**

↓                      ↓               ↓

`(n,t)`           `(n,t)`       `(n,t)`

⛶ ***Step 2:***

**Δw<sub>out</sub>     =     η ( a<sub>h2</sub><sup>T</sup>   •   Error<sub>out</sub> )**

↓                       ↓               ↓

`(h2,t)`         `(h2,n)`     `(n,t)`

**Δb<sub>out</sub>     =     η [ ∑ <sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup>  (Error<sub>out,i</sub>) ]**

↓                                 ↓

`(1,t)`                     `(1,t)`

Here **η** is the learning rate.

**w<sub>out</sub> = w<sub>out</sub> - Δw<sub>out</sub>**         (weight update.)

**b<sub>out</sub> = b<sub>out</sub> - Δb<sub>out</sub>**         (bias update.)

⛶ ***Step 3:***

**Error<sub>2</sub>     =     [Error<sub>out</sub>   •     w<sub>out</sub><sup>T</sup>]   ✴   Φ<sup>/</sup> (a<sub>h2</sub>)**

↓                     ↓                   ↓                   ↓

`(n,h2)`         `(n,t)`         `(t,h2)`       `(n,h2)`

Here, the symbol ✴ denotes element wise matrix multiplication. The symbol **Φ<sup>/</sup>** represents derivative of sigmoid function.

⛶ ***Step 4:***

**Δw<sub>h2</sub>     =     η ( a<sub>h1</sub><sup>T</sup>   •   Error<sub>2</sub> )**

↓                       ↓               ↓

`(h1,h2)`         `(h1,n)`     `(n,h2)`

**Δb<sub>h2</sub>     =     η [ ∑ <sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup>  (Error<sub>2,i</sub>) ]**

↓                                 ↓

`(1,h2)`                     `(1,h2)`

**w<sub>h2</sub> = w<sub>h2</sub> - Δw<sub>h2</sub>**         (weight update.)

**b<sub>h2</sub> = b<sub>h2</sub> - Δb<sub>h2</sub>**         (bias update.)

⛶ ***Step 5:***

**Error<sub>3</sub>     =     [Error<sub>2</sub>   •     w<sub>h2</sub><sup>T</sup>]   ✴   Φ<sup>/</sup> (a<sub>h1</sub>)**

↓                     ↓               ↓                   ↓

`(n,h1)`       `(n,h2)`     `(h2,h1)`       `(n,h1)`

⛶ ***Step 6:***

**Δw<sub>h1</sub>     =     η ( X<sup>T</sup>   •   Error<sub>3</sub> )**

↓                     ↓               ↓

`(d,h1)`         `(d,n)`     `(n,h1)`

**Δb<sub>h1</sub>     =     η [ ∑ <sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup>  (Error<sub>3,i</sub>) ]**

↓                                 ↓

`(1,h1)`                     `(1,h1)`

**w<sub>h1</sub> = w<sub>h1</sub> - Δw<sub>h1</sub>**         (weight update.)

**b<sub>h1</sub> = b<sub>h1</sub> - Δb<sub>h1</sub>**         (bias update.)

Answer (score 1):

For Forward Propagation, the dimension of the output from the first hidden layer must cope up with the dimensions of the second input layer.

As mentioned above, your input has dimension `(n,d)`. The output from hidden layer1 will have a dimension of `(n,h1)`. So the weights and bias for the second hidden layer must be `(h1,h2)` and `(h1,h2)` respectively.

So `w_h2` will be of dimension `(h1,h2)` and `b_h2` will be `(h1,h2)`.

The dimensions for the weights and bias for the output layer will be `w_output` will be of dimension `(h2,1)` and `b_output` will be `(h2,1)`.

The same you have to repeat in Backpropagation.

Comment: bumblebee: Thanks for the answer. I understand the forward propagation step for the second layer better now. Should the bias `b_h2` be of dimensions `(h2, 1)` instead of `(h1, h2)`? Also, can you describe the backpropagation step in a little more detail? I am confused about what I should do for backpropagation when I have two hidden layers.

Comment: The bias shouldn't be of dimension of `(h2,1)` because you are the adding the bias with the multiplication of `w_h2` and the output from the hidden layer 1. The dimension of the multiplication is `(h1,h2)`. In order to add, the bias should be of the same dimension too. That's why it is of dimension `(h1,h2)`

Comment: For back propagation, you will do the same in the reverse with the tranpose of all.